# How can i set labels of QHeaderView in PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt, qtablewidget, qheaderview

In Pyqt, I am trying to make the QHeaderView of a QTableWidget respond to right mouse clicks.
I have subclassed QHeaderView and i have overloaded the mousePressEvent.

Then i can set it as as the header of my custom QTableWidget, the DataTable class. However i don't understand how to set the labels of the header.

Thanks for helping!

Here is some code.

```
class Header( QtGui.QHeaderView ):
    def __init__ ( self, parent ):
        QtGui.QHeaderView.__init__( self, QtCore.Qt.Vertical, parent=parent )

    def mousePressEvent( self, event ):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            do_stuff()


class DataTable( QtGui.QTableWidget ):
    def __init__ ( self ):
        QtGui.QTableWidget.__init__( self )
        self.setShowGrid(True)

        self.header = Header( parent = self )
        self.header.setClickable(True)
        self.setHorizontalHeader( self.header )

    def set_header( self, labels ):
        ???
```

Answer (score 3):

This sample code should be useful:

```
import sys
import string
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class Header(QHeaderView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Header, self).__init__(Qt.Horizontal, parent)

        self.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.ctxMenu)
        self.hello = QAction("Hello", self)
        self.hello.triggered.connect(self.printHello)
        self.currentSection = None

    def printHello(self):
        data = self.model().headerData(self.currentSection, Qt.Horizontal)
        print data.toString()

    def ctxMenu(self, point):
        menu = QMenu(self)
        self.currentSection = self.logicalIndexAt(point)
        menu.addAction(self.hello)
        menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(point))


class Table(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Table, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setHorizontalHeader(Header(self))
        self.setColumnCount(3)
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['id', 'name', 'username'])
        self.populate()

    def populate(self):
        self.setRowCount(10)
        for i in range(10):
            for j,l in enumerate(string.letters[:3]):
                self.setItem(i, j, QTableWidgetItem(l)) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    t = Table()
    t.show()
    app.exec_()
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

The **QTableWidget** has a function called "setHorizontalHeaderLabels", simply supply your headers to it. Like so:

```
your_table_widget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["name", "phone number", "email"])
```

I would have added this as a comment to pedrotech, but I don't have enough rep for comments.